# What object captures local symmetries?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, symmetry

I have an ambiguous question. I know groups capture symmetry. Lie groups in particular capture continuous symmetry. What captures local symmetry? What even is local symmetry? Once again, this is an ambiguous question, so I’d appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: Do you have an example of "local symmetry" in mind?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was thinking in terms of manifolds and local symmetries. Maybe there exists an open set about each point that is a subset of a Lie group?

Comment: I like your question. Have you made any progress? The question still appears to be open to me so I thought I would ask.  I am struggling with global and local myself. I can only find mention of it in extremely complicated context but can't believe there are no simple examples unbeknowst to me.

Comment: @Sedumjoy I made a little progress before I gave up. I came across the concept o local groups (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/notes-on-local-groups/) and pseudogroups if you are interested.

Comment: @Spencer Krasier...thank  you so much. The link looks very interesting. I will read it. I am rather surprised that there are no answers to this question from the physics community.  Very clearly stated and in my opinion a very good question that  has far reaching applications in physics.